# I need to select the alternate route of two offered for an embedded map

Tags: google-maps

I am creating a page showing a detour people can take if a bridge is blocked due to crash etc. As a result I need to select the alternate route but the Embed api page doesn't offer any method to achieve this.

The support page simply tell me to ask the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Introduction), it is a service that calculates directions between locations using an HTTP request.

You can search for directions for several modes of transportation, including transit, driving, walking or cycling. Directions may specify origins, destinations and waypoints either as text strings (e.g. "Chicago, IL" or "Darwin, NT, Australia") or as latitude/longitude coordinates

Here in Directions API, you can set the [optional parameter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#RequestParameters) `alternatives` to `true` to specifies that the Directions service may provide more than one route alternative in the response. Note that providing route alternatives may increase the response time from the server.